# java.lang.reflect error with wowza and AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, wowza

I'm trying to upload files to S3 using a Wowza module made in Java.

I'm using Wowza Streaming Engine 4.1.0
Windows 8
Java SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)

My debug configuration VM argument already has `-Dcom.wowza.wms.native.base="win"` in it, which is what most search results for  "wowza java.lang.reflect" error suggest.

But I'm getting this error.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException|at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)|at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)|at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)|at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)|at com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleFunction.invoke(ModuleFunction.java:369
```

When my code tries to do this:

```
AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
```

Someone else seemed to have had this error [here](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?36732-AWS-SDK-S3-client-InvocationTargetException) but I don't see the answer.

I did, however, have problems initially installing the AWS SDK. I couldn't do it using the method described [in their official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup_install.html), so I did it using the method described in the second post of [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=550016#550016)

### EDIT:

I went and installed the AWS SDK the correct way, after downloading the data tools plugins. That didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AWS SDK 1.4.7 jar and the apache commons codec v1.9 fixed the problem for me

http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?38692-java-lang-reflect-error

### EDIT:

I had this error again when I installed Wowza on the server available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00IPTPABM/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2&qid=1412023081963). I replaced the v1.9 commons codec with the 1.3 commons codec, and it fixed it.

Windows 8 needs AWS SDK 1.4.7 and commons codec 1.9
Amazon Linux 2013.09.2 needs AWS SDK 1.4.7 and commons codec 1.3

Weird.